# add jars in an RCP app via an external eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jar, eclipse-rcp

I am learning rcp development, and currently I try to import some SWT widgets into an e4 RCP app, but I have problems.

I found jars for the XYGraph component [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/swt-xy-graph/downloads), and from the tutorial of lars Vogel, I learned to import some jars in an RCP app: I created a "Project from jars" in eclipse, in which I put all the jars (not only those mentionned above, but also others from the nebula project, but it not linked to the problem I get).
then, I added the plugin project with the jars in the manifest file of my RCP app(in the dependencies tab).
After that, I added the right "import" statements in my part file, and all should be good... but I get this error when I launch the RCP app(from the product file):
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/draw2d/IFigure
at the line 51

here is me RCP @postConstruct file: an arrow shows the line 51

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);

    LightweightSystem lws = new LightweightSystem(canvas);


    // create a new XY Graph.
    XYGraph xyGraph = new XYGraph();  <---- line 51
    xyGraph.setTitle("Simple Example");
    // set it as the content of LightwightSystem
    lws.setContents(xyGraph);

    // create a trace data provider, which will provide the data to the
    // trace.
    CircularBufferDataProvider traceDataProvider = new CircularBufferDataProvider(
            false);
    traceDataProvider.setBufferSize(100);
    traceDataProvider.setCurrentXDataArray(new double[] { 10, 23, 34, 45,
            56, 78, 88, 99 });
    traceDataProvider.setCurrentYDataArray(new double[] { 11, 44, 55, 45,
            88, 98, 52, 23 });

    // create the trace
    Trace trace = new Trace("Trace1-XY Plot", xyGraph.primaryXAxis,
            xyGraph.primaryYAxis, traceDataProvider);

    // set trace property
    trace.setPointStyle(PointStyle.XCROSS);

    // add the trace to xyGraph
    xyGraph.addTrace(trace);
}
```

do you have an idea about the origin of this error?

EDIT:
here are all the 4 files:

```
NebulaJars (jars plugin): MANIFEST.MF
https://paste.ofcode.org/mchNUQdCpGde3Tf2yKp8Qr
NebulaJars (jars plugin): build.properties
https://paste.ofcode.org/J6UHffTrjvGfWvHSqunQks
RCP project:
MANIFEST.MF
https://paste.ofcode.org/hR7ZkU85qXAqBPjTam53nV
build.properties
https://paste.ofcode.org/DWEc8SV9U85rHMKk4Eb9X3
```

EDIT 2:
[image]

Comment: Have you added the plugin containing these jars to your plugin's dependencies? Have you exported the packages in the plugin containing the jars? Show us the MANIFEST.MF and build.properties for both plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the corresponding exported packages in runtime tab of the manifest file created for XYGraph (and others...) plugin ?

EDIT 1 :
Try to tune your plugins from your launch configuration. You can access launch configuration from Run->Run Configurations... menu. Check if your plugin configuration is valid.

[image]

Comment: hello, I corrected this : I found the correct jar on the net, and added this to the jars plugin (using your hint) and ... I have other errors, unxepected : the last one  is : "org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/resource/ColorRegistry", although the correct class is in the "plugin dependencies" of my RCP project. I don't understand why such classes are not in the classpath

Comment: I have "org.eclipse.jface" in the dependencies of my manifest file

Comment: Your product is based on plugins, try to add jface in its dependencies tab.

Comment: it is already there : in MANIFEST.MF>"dependencies">"required plugins">org.eclipse.jface

Comment: Nop ! Not in your manifest plugin, try to add it in your PRODUCT dependencies tab. Or try to synchronize your product with your plugin (first tab of your product file : overview).

Comment: plz have a look a a part of my product dependencies... it's faster for me to answer you with a picture! anyway, it seems to be there also

Comment: Sorry : are you starting your app from a product or from a launch configuration ?

Comment: from the product. never with launch configuration

Comment: should I modify launch configuration ?

Comment: Then try to check if plugins configuration is ok with validate plug-ins button. Please see my edited response. And tell us if you have any error...

Comment: I mean the probl is still there but validating didn't resolve it

Comment: I found an answer : instead of downloading individual jars, I went to the nebula update site and installed the product, then I followed this tuto : https://www.asegno.com/2015/eclipse/swt-xy-graph-charting/. simple, but not easy to find! thx again

Comment: ... and it is necessary to click on "product file"- dependencies tab- "add required plugins"